# Total value in file using shell script where values in gb,mb,kb,b

Tags: linux, shell, automation, sum, devops

I have a file where values in a column with unit mb,kb,b and gb, I want total of these value using shell script and output will come in Total gb

cat test_file

```
24k
556m
1.2g
6.2m
17m
24k
254b
30g
1.6g
28k
120b
```

I'm able to convert byte data into mb but stuck to convert kb and sum total of all

```
test=0 
for i in `cat test_file` 
do 
b=echo $i|tr -d '[:alpha:]' 
a=echo $i|tr -d '/0-9,\./' 
if [ "$a" == "b" ]; then 
b=($b/1024) fi test=echo $test + $b | bc 
done 
result=$(echo "scale=2; $test / 1024" | bc) 
echo $result
```

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I tried but couldn't get success, not getting the exact result

Comment: what **did** you try, which tools were you attempting to use, what was the approach?

Comment: @Anup, No one will say anything(apart from guidance) even you will add a non-working code in your question, so please always do add them in questions.

Comment: Using awk and sed command

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I'm able to convert byte data into mb but stuck to convert kb and sum total of all
```
test=0
for i in `cat test_file `
do
b=`echo $i|tr -d '[:alpha:]'`
a=`echo $i|tr -d '/0-9,\./'`

if [ "$a" == "b" ]; then
b=($b/1024)
fi
test=`echo $test + $b | bc`
done
result=$(echo "scale=2; $test / 1024" | bc)

echo $result
```

Comment: @Anup, Thank you Anup for sharing your attempts, please do add them in your question, I have posted an answer now, thank you.

Comment: @Anup : Please format your script properly; the way it is posted, it would be simply syntactically incorrect. BTW, do you **have** to do this in POSIX shell? If you would use zsh, you would have fractional arithmetic built-in and would not need to revert to `bc`.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** Using `switch` case in GNU `awk`:

```
awk '
{
last_char=tolower(substr($0,length($0)))
switch(last_char){
  case "k":
    sum+=($0+0)/(1024*1024)
    break
  case "m":
    sum+=($0+0)/(1024)
    break
  case "g":
    sum+=$0+0
    break
  case "b":
    sum+=($0+0)/(1024*1024*1024)
    break
  case "?":
    print "Line is not matching anything here...."
}
}
END{
  print sum
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Could you please try following, this solution is using `if`, `else` conditions.

```
awk '
{
  if($0~/[kK]$/){
    sum+=($0+0)/(1024*1024)
  }
  if($0~/[mM]$/){
    sum+=($0+0)/(1024)
  }
  if($0~/[gG]$/){
    sum+=$0+0
  }
  if($0~/bB]$/){
    sum+=($0+0)/(1024*1024*1024)
  }
}
END{
  print sum
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Anup, Code gives me output as `33.3657` and when I do calculations manually it is `33.3656` it looks Good to me, please do lemme know on same?

Comment: @Anup, Could you please do lemme know if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl version:

```
perl -nle 'BEGIN {for (qw(k m g t)) {$m{$_}=1000**++$i}}; ($v,$u)=/([\d\.]+)([kmgt])?/; $v*=$m{$u} if $u; $t+=$v; END {print "Total $t Bytes\n"}' test_file
```

Or on multiple lines for readability:

```
perl -nle '
  BEGIN { for (qw(k m g t)) {$m{$_}=1000**++$i} }; # create multipliers hash
  ($v,$u) = /([\d\.]+)([kmgt])?/;                  # get value and optional unit
  $v *= $m{$u} if $u;                              # multiply to get bytes (if unit was specified)
  $t += $v;
  END { print "Total $t Bytes\n"}' test_file
```

This gives megabytes as 1'000'000 bytes. If your values represent binary Mebibytes etc., replace 1000 by 1024.

A more readable version of the initialization of the multiplier hash would be:

```
BEGIN { @m{ qw(k m g t) } = (1000, 1000**2, 1000**3, 1000**4) };
```

If your units may also be written in mixed case, add `$_=lc;` before the regex to first make it all lowercase.